# Using existing Windows 8 after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10, license, licensing

The first part of my question was where can I get my Windows 8 Key but that has already been answered elsewhere.

The second part is if I do the free upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1, can I use the old Windows 8 Licence in a VM Guest or on another PC? Or is that against Microsoft's licencing laws?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The W8 key is absorbed into the w10 upgrade, so no, but you can go back to W8 on the original pc if you decide later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suspicious it would not activate correctly, as the Windows 8 key is likely in your UEFI and tied to the hardware. The virtual machine will report different hardware.

This should answer your question regarding licencing

https://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/Pages/support-faq.aspx#fbid=NGO47IauTWg

> Q. Can I install OEM software on a virtual machine (VMware)?
>
> A. You can install OEM software in a virtual environment as long as you have
> a separate license for each instance of the software. It is fine to
> use the OEM version as long as it is properly licensed. To be clear, a
> separate version of the software must be installed for both the
> “standard” and “virtual” installations.

As your licence is now 'activated' for Windows 10, it would be against the licence.

Comment: Interested why this attracted a down vote?

Answer (score 0):

No. It won't activate. You can use it to install Win8.1, but you'll need to activate online, and that's where it'll be rejected. The key is marked at MS as "used".